# Const correctness in C++ operator overloading returns

Tags: c++, coding-style, operator-overloading, constants

I'm a little confused as to why I've been told to return const foo from a binary operator in c++ instead of just foo.

I've been reading Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in C++", and in the chapter on operator overloading, he says that "by making the return value [of an over-loading binary operator] const, you state that only a const member function can be called for that return value. This is const-correct, because it prevents you from storing potentially valuable information in an object that will be most likely be lost".

However, if I have a plus operator that returns const, and a prefix increment operator, this code is invalid:

```
class Integer{
int i;

public:
    Integer(int ii): i(ii){ }
    Integer(Integer&);

    const Integer operator+();
    Integer operator++();
};


int main(){

Integer a(0);
Integer b(1);

Integer c( ++(a + b));
}
```

To allow this sort of assignment, wouldn't it make sense to have the + operator return a non-const value? This could be done by adding const_casts, but that gets pretty bulky, doesn't it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say ++x, you're saying "add 1 to x, store the result back into x, and tell me what it was".  This is the preincrement operator.  But, in ++(a+b), how are you supposed to "store the result back into a+b"?

Certainly you could store the result back into the temporary which is presently holding the result of a+b, which would vanish soon enough.  But if you didn't really care where the result was stored, why did you increment it instead of just adding one?

Answer (score 4):

FYI, `++(a + b)` is illegal even with PODs (plain old data types, like `int`). So it makes sense not to allow it for your own class types either. Try this:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = ++(a+b);
```

GCC returns `error: lvalue required as increment operand`.

In your case, it would be preferable make your copy constructor take a `const Integer` argument, and create your `Integer c` like this instead:

```
Integer c(a + b + Integer(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy constructors usually take a **const** reference, solving that problem for you.

(Having non-const copy ctor implies some transfer of resources, which can be useful sometimes, but for 99% of all situations, it's not needed)

Answer (score 0):

I believe OP's example would be suitable to the question if the addition operator is substituted with any other binary operator that returns a reference, for example an assignment operator:

```
Integer c( ++(a = b));
```

I came here wondering whether I should make my assignment operator return a const or a non-const reference. [Some tutorials](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/) use non-const versions, contrary to "Thinking in C++"'s advice. And [some other references](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html) give reasoning behind that:

> Notice that the returned reference is not declared const. This can be a bit confusing, because it allows you to write crazy stuff like this:
>
> > MyClass a, b, c;
> >
> > ...
> >
> > (a = b) = c;  // What??
>
> At first glance, you might want to prevent situations like this, by having operator= return a const reference. However, statements like this will work with primitive types. And, even worse, some tools actually rely on this behavior. Therefore, it is important to return a non-const reference from your operator=. The rule of thumb is, "If it's good enough for ints, it's good enough for user-defined data-types."